# How can I feed 3d array into neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Here I have data which look like this

```
0.25    #single value

[0.25, 0.027777777777777776, 0.3055555555555556, 
0.2222222222222222, 0.3611111111111111, 0.25,
 0.25, 0.05555555555555555, 0.25, 
0.027777777777777776, 0.2777777777777778, 0.08333333333333333, 
0.3055555555555556, 0.08333333333333333, 0.2777777777777778, 
0.19444444444444445]       #16 floats

[[0.25, 0.027777777777777776, 0.3055555555555556, 
0.2222222222222222, 0.3611111111111111, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.05555555555555555, 0.25, 
0.027777777777777776, 0.2777777777777778, 0.08333333333333333, 
0.3055555555555556, 0.08333333333333333, 0.2777777777777778, 
0.19444444444444445], 4]      #16 float followed by class

[[[0.25, 0.027777777777777776, 0.3055555555555556, 
0.2222222222222222, 0.3611111111111111, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.05555555555555555, 0.25, 
0.027777777777777776, 0.2777777777777778, 0.08333333333333333, 
0.3055555555555556, 0.08333333333333333, 0.2777777777777778, 
0.19444444444444445], 4],
[[0.3611111111111111, 0.1388888888888889, 0.16666666666666666, 
0.4166666666666667, 0.0, 0.05555555555555555, 
0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.19444444444444445, 
0.3055555555555556, 0.16666666666666666, 0.2222222222222222, 
0.05555555555555555, 0.1388888888888889, 0.3888888888888889, 
0.2222222222222222], 1]]         #actual dataset sample
```

16 floating point value array followed by class which it belong

How can I feed this in to a neural network to make a classifier model

Comment: So your data is `n x m x k` where `n`,`m` and `k` is the size of....?

Comment: x=np.array(data)
x.shape   (5250, 2)????